# QGIS 3x Update existing field autoselection in field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I want to have the "Distance [meters]" column autoselected when launching a data field calculator.

It's driven by a multitude of records, which I want to put by using the expression (individual for every ID). As I have several records, the job is quite tedious. I have to select the field for updates every time.

[image]

Is there any way to set the target field for updates and make it autoloaded when running a field calculator?

I think, some hint can be here:

[Is it possible to have auto-updating area fields?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122365/is-it-possible-to-have-auto-updating-area-fields)

but it looks like there is no Autofield plugin for QGIS 3x

[Functionalities of expression builder in Autofield plugin available in QGIS 3.4?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326111/functionalities-of-expression-builder-in-autofield-plugin-available-in-qgis-3-4)

How can I have the field auto populated in the data attribute table calculator?

Comment: If you dont need a permanent field you may consider using a virtual field that will auto-update